# Cannot figure out where to find the number of threads that python is seeing

Tags: python, cron, process

I am running into an issue that I do not fully understand.

My crontab runs python jobs on a schedule as it's supposed to. Recently they've started failing when loading the `pandas` library with the following error :

```
OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: pthread_create failed for thread 4 of 8: Resource temporarily unavailable
OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: RLIMIT_NPROC 126940 current, 126940 max
OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: pthread_create failed for thread 5 of 8: Resource temporarily unavailable
OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: RLIMIT_NPROC 126940 current, 126940 max
OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: pthread_create failed for thread 6 of 8: Resource temporarily unavailable
OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: RLIMIT_NPROC 126940 current, 126940 max
OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: pthread_create failed for thread 7 of 8: Resource temporarily unavailable
OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: RLIMIT_NPROC 126940 current, 126940 max
```

Even though I do not know why so many processes would be created by my jobs, this is still a fairly straightforward error.

So I tried to keep track of the number of open processes to see if there was a specific job triggering the increase. I did that using:

```
ps -eLo pid,cmd,nlwp | wc -l
```

which gives me a fairly stable number of around 5k even when the job is failing with the above message (so I was expecting to see ~126k processes).

I am at a loss here : which command do I need to run to be able to keep track of the number of processes that Python sees (i.e ~126940).

Comment: how much memory does your computer have? look at `/sys/fs/cgroup/pids/user.slice/user-1000.slice/pids.current` and `/sys/fs/cgroup/pids/user.slice/user-1000.slice/pids.max` (you might have to replace the 1000 with your user group number). Look at `/proc/sys/kernel/ns_last_pid` before and after your job to see how much it changed.

Comment: 32gb ram which is not used as far as I know. But my question really is where can I track that 126940 number ? When I check number of processes I get 5k.